# PostgreSQL Table size and partition consideration

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I am working on a use case where initial data load for name table in PostgreSQL DB will be around 650 million rows with average row size of 0.6 KB bringing table size up to 400 GB. After that there could be up to 20,000 inserts or updates on daily basis.

I am new to PostgreSQL, want to check if I should consider partitioning looking at the table size.

Updating some information from Comments section:

It is an OLTP application for Identity resolution for business names, this is one specific table where all the business names are stored along with the metadata such as Start Date, End Date and any incoming name is matched with existing names to identify if it is related to another business. This table is updated throughout the day using batch files from different data sources.

Also, we are not planning to expire or remove any data from this table.

Comment: We would need to know more about your data and how you plan to use it to advise. With such a large amount of data, and a high number of inserts, a [data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) might be a better solution.

Comment: Hello, it is an OLTP application for Identity resolution for business names, this is one specific table where all the business names are stored along with the metadata such as Start Date, End Date and any incoming name is matched with existing names to identify if it is related to another business. This table is updated throughout the day using batch files from different data sources.

Comment: Partitioning will often be driven in a case like this by how the data will eventually be expired/removed.  How do you plan on doing that?

Comment: If partitioning should be used for performance reasons then this will only show an effect if all queries always include the partition key. Queries _without_ using the partition key in the WHERE clause will most likely be slower. You also lose flexibility with foreign keys _referencing_ the partitioned table

Comment: Sounds like a data warehouse, not an oltp database. Partitioning makes sense for a 400GB table, but you have to know what kind of data is in that table and how you use it. Without all the details, including all the tiny details, it's hard to give you any advise.